# Create a decorator in Python, which remembers last output of the function

Tags: python, function, caching, decorator

I need to create a decorator which remembers last call result of the function which it decorates. For example, I have a function:

```
def summarize(*args):
    result = ""
    for i in args:
        result += i
    print('New result = ', result)
    return result
```

And I need to use decorator (without any classes or smth), to make it like that:

```
summarize("he", "llo")
>>> "Previous result = 'None'"
>>> "New result = 'hello'"
summarize("good", "bye")
>>> "Previous result = 'hello'"
>>> "New result = 'goodbye'"
```

I'm new to decorators and now I don't have any idea how to make it like that. I get needed result only when I try to call the function twice in one run.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the function twice in one run"? Should the cache be cleared if any other function is called between two calls of the function? Why don't you want to use a class? What do you consider "smth" similar to a class?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I mean, I don't need it working like that:
`summarize('he', 'llo')
summarize('good', 'by')
--run the code--
"Previous result = 'None'"
"New result = 'hello'"

"Previous result = 'hello'"
"New result = 'goodbye'"`

I want it working for every new code run, if you understand what I mean

Comment: "I don't have any idea how to make it like that" isn't an answerable question - this is not a code-writing service. What specifically don't you understand about it? Did you manage previously to write *any* kind of decorator, for example? What do you imagine are the logical steps the decorated function should take when it is called? (What *strategy* do you want to use, to remember the previous value?) How would you write `summarize` so that it solves the problem *directly* (without being decorated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below :

```py
def historic_results(func):
    # retrive historic outputs from hitoric_outputs.txt file if it exists
    with open('historic_outputs.txt', "r") as f:
        try:
           previous_outputs = f.readlines()
        except:
           previous_outputs = []

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        
        if not previous_outputs : print("Previous Result:", None)
        if previous_outputs: 
            for item in previous_outputs: print("Previous Result:", item)

        # append the output in the historic outputs txt file
        with open('historic_outputs.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(func(*args, **kwargs) + "\n")
        
        print("New Result", func(*args, **kwargs))

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner


@historic_results
def summarize(*args):
    result = ""
    for i in args:
        result += i
    return result
```

Test :

```py
summarize("hel", "lo")
summarize("Ami", "ne")
summarize("stupid", "_beaver")
```

Output:

```py
Previous Result: None
New Result hello

Previous Result: hello
New Result Amine

Previous Result: hello
Previous Result: Amine
New Result stupid_beaver
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but is it possible to make it not for one by one function call in the code, but for every new run of the same function?

Comment: The results can be stored either on the function, a closure or a dictionary, which also allows for a separate cache per function. There is no need to use a ``global``.

Comment: @stupid_beaver it will work for every new function call / run

Comment: @AmineBTG I mean, is it possible for every code run? Not just calling the function several times in the code

Comment: In order to have the hostoric for every code run, you need to store the historic outputs in some sort of a file or a database. Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @stupid_beaver just modified the code so the historic outputs will be saved in a txt file. That way, the historic output will be displayed every code run

Comment: @AmineBTG yes, I think that was smth that I was looking for, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
prev_result = None

def remember_result(func):

    def wrapper(*args):
        global prev_result
        print(f"Prev result = '{prev_result}'")
        prev_result = func(*args)
    return wrapper

@remember_result
def summarize(*args):
    result = ""
    for i in args:
        result += i
    print('New result = ', result)
    return result
```